# Pass props to stateless component style(css)

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the color of child component, Now i am passing the color's from parent component.

**Parent**

```
<ChildBox backColor = {this.state.backgroundColor} />
```

Now this backColor I want pass for child but the below code is not working

```
const ChildBox = ({backColor}) => {
return(
<div style={backgroundColor: {backColor}} >
<h5>{backColor}</h5>
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`style` in JSX needs to be an `object` with `camelCase` keys passed on to the element like

```
const ChildBox = ({backColor}) => {
    return(
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: backColor }} >
        <h5>{backColor}</h5>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped Ramya